# Parsing decimal numbers, some of which lack a decimal separator, in JSON data using JSON-Simple (Java)

Tags: java, json, parsing, double, json-simple

I am trying to use the [*JSON-Simple*](https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/) JSON processor library.

When parsing JSON fragment such as:

```json
"speed":1.13
```

…I call `get` and cast as a `Double`. No problem.

```java
Double speed = ( Double ) wind.get( "speed" );
```

But then I encounter a value without a decimal fraction. Ex: `1` rather than `1.0`.

```json
"speed":1
```

Granted, the publisher of this data should have written `"speed":1.0`. But they did not.

My `get` with casting throws an exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Long cannot be cast to class java.lang.Double (java.lang.Long and java.lang.Double are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

Apparently *JSON-Simple* insisted on parsing the JSON value of `1` as a `Long`. So I need a workaround, a way to tell *JSON-Simple* how to parse this particular element.

➥ Is there a way to tell JSON-Simple to parse the string inputs as `Double` regardless of whether a [decimal separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator) (a decimal point) is present?

➥ Even better, can I tell JSON-Simple to parse the string input for a particular JSON element as [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) to bypass the [inaccuracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems) of [floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic)? (that is, going from `String` to `BigDecimal` without involving floating-point along the way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use later version

You are using the original JSON-Simple library led by Fang Yidong. Later versions 2 and 3 were developed as a fork at [this Clifton Labs page](https://cliftonlabs.github.io/json-simple/) on GitHub, led by Davin Loegering.

The original does not support `BigDecimal`. [The fork](https://cliftonlabs.github.io/json-simple/) does supports `BigDecimal`. See the [`getBigDecimal`](https://cliftonlabs.github.io/json-simple/target/apidocs/com/github/cliftonlabs/json_simple/JsonObject.html#getBigDecimal-com.github.cliftonlabs.json_simple.JsonKey-) method.

The fork has changed the original library quite a bit. See the *History* section of [that Clifton Labs page](https://cliftonlabs.github.io/json-simple/).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of casting try

`Double.parseDouble(wind.get( "speed" ).toString())`